# Displaying more than 2 decimals for currency field in Report

Tags: reporting, formatting, decimal

[image]

I have a one currency field in an object, and I have kept 5 decimal places to that currency field.
while showing the same field in a report it is showing only 2 decimal places.

How can I change the settings in the report so that I can see the 5 decimal values? e.g.

```
23.12345
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you provide some details of your report ? I tried to replicate this and my report show the currency field entirely.

Comment: Are you having the same problem as in [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br58)

Comment: I am using multiple currencies in our organization

Comment: If you're using multiple currencies, perhaps have a look at this knowledge article: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000187718&language=en_US

Comment: @KevinLam, that is exactly what's going on. You should submit that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using multiple currencies, please have a look at this knowledge article: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000187718&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried display custom Number formula based on your currency field in this report?
Such field allows you set number of decimal places.
I believe this should solve your problem

Comment: yes .I tried that one .In it will ask for summarize field.it will unit price sum min max avg .it will not work